Getting aria-describedby warning while using @dnd-kit/core library
I am using @dnd-kit/core library for Drag & drop functionality, but I am getting this particular warning every time when the component mounts.
Warning: Prop `aria-describedby` did not match. Server: "DndDescribedBy-1" Client: "DndDescribedBy-2"     at div     at th     at _c10 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/ui/table.tsx:97:11)     at DraggableTableHeader (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/data-table/data-table.tsx:116:11)     at SortableContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@dnd-kit/sortable/dist/sortable.esm.js:312:5)     at tr     at _c8 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/ui/table.tsx:83:11)     at thead     at _c2 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/ui/table.tsx:41:11)     at table     at div     at _c (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/ui/table.tsx:20:11)     at div     at div     at DndContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@dnd-kit/core/dist/core.esm.js:2864:5)     at DataTable (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/data-table/data-table.tsx:204:11)     at div     at div     at div     at PaymentsPage (Server)     at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:242:11)     at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)     at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)     at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)     at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:346:11)     at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)     at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9)     at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)     at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)     at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:367:11)     at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:242:11)     at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)     at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)     at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)     at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)     at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:346:11)     at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)     at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:152:9)     at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)     at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)     at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:367:11)     at body     at html     at RootLayout (Server)     at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)     at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)     at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)     at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)     at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:11)     at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)     at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js:321:11)     at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:207:11)     at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)     at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)     at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:577:13)     at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:112:27)     at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:117:11) window.console.error @ app-index.js:33 console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:63 printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:94 error @ react-dom.development.js:68 warnForPropDifference @ react-dom.development.js:32715 diffHydratedGenericElement @ react-dom.development.js:34933 diffHydratedProperties @ react-dom.development.js:35113 hydrateInstance @ react-dom.development.js:36127 prepareToHydrateHostInstance @ react-dom.development.js:7246 completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:19769 completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:25963 performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:25759 workLoopConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js:25734 renderRootConcurrent @ react-dom.development.js:25690 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24504 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:256 flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:225 performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:534 Show 18 more frames Show less

I don't know if this is Next.js issue (hydration), or a library specific issue. How do I remove this warning?
I tried implementing the drag & drop feature (it works fine), but I get this warning everytime which I want to get rid of.

This is a Next.js SSR issue. There are basically two ways to fix this:

Remove dnd from SSR with a dynamic import as mentioned here.
Add an ID to the dnd context provider as mentioned here.

You can check out the linked issue in general to get more information on why this is happening.

I resolved the DnD warning by adding a unique ID to the DndContext component. This approach worked perfectly! Ensure that the ID is unique throughout your entire app to prevent conflicts with other elements.
<DndContext
        id="draggable-table-01"
        sensors={sensors}
        modifiers={[restrictToHorizontalAxis]}
        onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
        onDragOver={onDragOver}
        collisionDetection={closestCenter}
    >
        <SortableContext items={columns.map((i) => i.key)} strategy={horizontalListSortingStrategy}>
            <DragIndexContext.Provider value={dragIndex}>
                <Table
                    rowKey="key"
                    columns={columns}
                    dataSource={dataSource}
                    components={{
                        header: { cell: TableHeaderCell },
                        body: { cell: TableBodyCell },
                    }}
                />
            </DragIndexContext.Provider>
        </SortableContext>
        <DragOverlay>
            <th style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', padding: 16 }}>
                {columns[columns.findIndex((i) => i.key === dragIndex.active)]?.title as React.ReactNode}
            </th>
        </DragOverlay>
    </DndContext>

